# Web scraping table with a selector that dynamically modifies the table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape one table from a website.
The problem is that it has a selector to choose if the table is aggregated by Country, State or City, which changes the data that is displayed. By default the table shows data for 'Country' level, but I would like to scrape the data at a 'State' level. This is the site:

https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry

And I'm using the following code:

```
page = requests.get('https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all("table")
table = tables[0]
tab_data = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all(["th","td"])]
                        for row in table.find_all("tr")]
df = pd.DataFrame(tab_data)
```

Which gives me the 'Country' table, how can I manage to get the 'State' table?

Thanks

Comment: Standard request modules don't handle dynamic data generation. You'll need to use a webdriver like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

Comment: There is a data set download functionality above the table which you can click and download the data for country, state or city via selenium

Comment: Thanks @Vin and Wondercricket. Would you mind giving a example on how to use selenium for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code which is implemented using Selenium. Below script is first opening the browser and then waiting for the drop down to be located,looping over all 3 options of drop down. However, there is a button which says download data set and when you click on it will give you all 3 options data in one **csv** file. I have implemented the below script which is right now mimicking and downloading the data set by clicking on button but you can leverage this for other usage or requirement because you have asked for an example.

> Make sure you donwload the chrome driver and mention the path **chromedriver.exe** of your system here on **this line webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def scrape_all_data():
    url = 'https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry'

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    print("Opening Chrome Browser..")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options) #download chrome drivier and mention the path of .exe 

    driver.get(url)

    wait1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)
    wait1.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/select'))) #wait till the select will be located.

    lst_to_traverse = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/select')))) #selecting the select element for further looping or usage

    for option in lst_to_traverse.options:
        print(option.text) #print the selected option ex:- country, state or city
        lst_to_traverse.select_by_visible_text(option.text)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/div[1]/button').click() #download the dataset
        time.sleep(1)
        break
    

scrape_all_data()
```